# Why declare Exchange in RabbitMQ?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I am working on a project with RabbitMQ. My code is below.

**Producer:**

```
public static void Main()
{
    var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
    using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    {
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare("hello", false, false, false, null);

            string message = "Hello World!";
            var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

            channel.BasicPublish("", "hello", null, body);
            Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Consumer with Exchange declared:**

```
public static void Main()
{
    var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
    using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    {
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.ExchangeDeclare("hello", "direct",false, false, false, null);
            channel.QueueDeclare("hello", false, false, false, null);

            var consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);
            channel.BasicConsume("hello", true, consumer);

            Console.WriteLine(" [*] Waiting for messages." +
                                     "To exit press CTRL+C");
            while (true)
            {
                var ea = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue();

                var body = ea.Body;
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Consumer without Exchange declared:**

```
public static void Main()
{
    var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
    using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    {
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare("hello", false, false, false, null);

            var consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);
            channel.BasicConsume("hello", true, consumer);

            Console.WriteLine(" [*] Waiting for messages." +
                                     "To exit press CTRL+C");
            while (true)
            {
                var ea = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue();

                var body = ea.Body;
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Both consumer code works well, so what's the main use of declaring exchange? I am confused. Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Publishing to **queues** lets you only implement basic publish-subscribe scenarios, where the producer and consumer use the exact queue. In case of multiple consumers a single queue of messages is distributed between multiple consumers.

Publishing to **exchanges** lets you create complicated scenarios, because of **routing** between exchanges and queues.

For example, a **fanout exchange** routes messages to all bound queues. This way, you can have one producer and multiple consumers and each message is **copied** to all bound queues independently and received independently.

Another example of exchange, a **topic exchange** routes messages to bound queues based on *routing key* in a message and a pattern on a queue. This introduces an interesting possibility of *tagging* messages and delivering them conditionally.

For a complete reference of exchange types and their profiles refer to the documentation:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html

https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html